# Upsert DML Operation

Tags: apex, dml, upsert, dml-operations, mixed-dml

Consider the below code. I thought the way upsert DML works is that if it sees that there is a new record with matching key (here in this case there is already an account with `Name = Acme` and `BillingCity = Austin`), it will not insert the new account in line number 6 and will just update the existing account with the `Phone = '412 9012333'`. But however it doesn't work that way and it inserts the account if it finds a new Account statement. Please correct me if my understanding is correct and whether I am missing something.

```
1 List<Account> newAcct = new List<Account>();
2 newAcct = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity  FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Acme'];
3 for(Account c : newAcct){
4    c.BillingCity = 'Austin';
5 }
6 Account newAcct2 = new Account(Name ='Acme', BillingCity = 'Austin', Phone = '412 9012333');
7 newAcct.add(newAcct2);
8 upsert newAcct;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how upsert works. It works by using Id, or an External ID, to determine if the record should be inserted or updated. You would need some sort of external ID field to work with:

```
List<Account> newAcct = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity  FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Acme'];
Integer externalIdCounter = 0;
for(Account c : newAcct) {
  c.External_Id__c = (externalIdCounter++)+'';
}
update newAcct;
Account newAcct2 = new Account(External_Id__c='0', Name ='Acme', BillingCity = 'Austin', Phone = '412 9012333');
newAcct.add(newAcct2);
upsert newAcct Account.External_Id__c;
```

Upsert does not use multiple keys/composite keys. It requires you to set up a special field for the purpose of upserting, or using the Salesforce ID as the key (which is the default if you do not specify a field).

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean I need to use Id for standard or custom objects and cannot use any other fields such as Name? External id should be used if we need to create an external relationship right?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy Right, you need a custom field to use as an External ID. The REST API can use the Name field, though.

Comment: thank you. So from your explanation I need to give id if I need to update an existing record and insert new records for new records right?

Comment: I found that you can use Account.fields.Name to specify the key. I’m surprised you didn’t mention this?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy I thought you could, but I tried it and it didn't want to take, so I figured they changed something. If it's working for you, then that would work just fine. Just remember each name must be unique or you'll get an error.

Comment: In your example why have you not used upsert newAcct Account.fields.External_Id__c in your last statement? Sorry to ask you a lot of questions. I am just confused.

Comment: May I ask why you have used Accounts.External_Id__c in your last statement? Is that the right syntax? Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Krishnamurthy You use that to specify which field to upsert against. External_Id__c is a placeholder for whatever you need it to be.